# Unexpected ModelForm has no class specified error

Tags: django, django-forms

So I am trying to create a form for a model which specifies extra fields that I added to User.

The forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'company',
            'birth_date',
        ]
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company     = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    address     = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date  = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


from .forms import ProfileForm
from .models import Profile


def profile_settings_view(request):
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'userinfo/settings.html', context)
```

So my error output is:

ValueError at /settings/
ModelForm has no model class specified.

But how is that possible, I used model = Profile why do I get this error then?

Comment: I think it should be `Meta` instead of `meta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `meta` to `Meta` in `ProfileForm`.

**Meta class**: is just a class container which defines some metadata attached to the model. It defines various options like ordering, database table name etc. Including Meta class to a class is optional. For more information read [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/)